# Mango Tile Flipping and back content

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

When I pinned my test application to the start. The tile which has 2 sides flipped only twice. Is this the default behavior. Can we change this behavior, so that it flip always?

Is it possible to change the font size of the back content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we change this behavior, so that it flip always?

No, you can't change the standard behaviour.

> Is it possible to change the font size of the back content?

Only by drawing the tile as a image, for that [I've written a guide](http://windcape.posterous.com/how-to-live-tile-with-scheduled-agent)